# Need custom listview example in android

Tags: android, listview

I need custom listview example in android.
In each row it should contain 3 textviews .
And when i click on items it should change to another layout by passing parameters.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple google serach http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/ 
http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327